# read in chunks with async-std

Tags: rust, rust-async-std

I'm trying to implement something similar to reading a file in Java with [AsynchronousByteChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousByteChannel.html#read(java.nio.ByteBuffer,A,java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler)) like

```java
   AsynchronousFileChannel channel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(path...

   channel.read(buffer,... new CompletionHandler<Integer, ByteBuffer>() {
      @Override
      public void completed(Integer result) {
          ...use buffer         
      }
```

i.e. read as much as OS gives, process, ask for more and so on.
What would be the most straightforward way to achieve this with async_std?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`read`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.7.0/async_std/io/trait.Read.html) method of the `async_std::io::Read` trait:

```rust
use async_std::prelude::*;

let mut reader = obtain_read_somehow();
let mut buf = [0; 4096]; // or however large you want it

// read returns a Poll<Result> so you have to handle the result
loop {
    let byte_count = reader.read(&mut buf).await?;
    if byte_count == 0 {
        // 0 bytes read means we're done
        break;
    }
    // call whatever handler function on the bytes read
    handle(&buf[..byte_count]);
}
```